# How to handle HttpClient Keep-Alive response header with max and timeout

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient, keep-alive

HttpClient starts throwing exceptions after a few requests to a specific server. After some tests I noticed that it always stops working at request number 33. The server sends this response header:

> Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=32

I have tried to dispose HttpClient at request number 32 or less but it does not solve the problem.

How should I handle it in order to send requests without problems to this server ?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `HttpClient.Dispose` or explicitly setting the `Connection: close` header

```
client.DefaultHeaders.Add("Connection", "close");
```

Comment: Not working. After disposing the HttpClient the server rejects the request.